# Oracle Execution Plan

Tags: oracle, toad, sql-execution-plan

I am using Oracle 11g and Toad for Oracle. How can I display execution plan for queries? 
In Sql server management studio execution plan can be displayed as graphical format. Is there any functionality/tool like that on Toad for oracle?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

CTRL-E

Make sure you've ended the query with a semi-colon (and the query above)

Edit:

You need to set-up the TOAD plan table for use.  If you think it's already setup on your DB then you may just need to be granted access.  Alternatively in my slightly older version of TOAD it's under:

Database --> Administer --> Server Side Objects Wizard.  From here you can create the plan table(s) in a schema that you choose.

Comment: I have an error. "Ora-02403: plan table does not have correct format"

Comment: ORA-02403 means that the plan table was created using one version and at a later date the database was upgraded to a version that requires a different plan table. Find the UTLXplan.sql file for your current version, drop the existing plan table, and rebuild it using the script.

Answer (score 2):

You should create the PLAN_TABLE using a script provided by Oracle 
which is named UTLXPLAN.SQL and is located in one of the installation folders 
on the database server.

Then, you should use the EXPLAIN PLAN statement for generating a plan for a SQL statement, like this: 
EXPLAIN PLAN SET STATEMENT_ID = 'your_identifier_for_this_plan' 
FOR 
... your statement ... ;

Then, you can use either a select from PLAN_TABLE (usually using a hierarchical query) or the DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY_PLAN procedure to display the plan. 
In the same folder where the UTLXPLAN.SQL file is located, there usually exist 
examples of using this procedure.

Also, in SQL*PLUS you can use the SET AUTOTRACE feature.

Answer (score 1):

For TOAD FOR ORACLE

this helped me [How do I view the Explain Plan in Oracle Sql developer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30070910/how-do-i-view-the-explain-plan-in-oracle-sql-developer), I just write what they did in sql developer and wrote in the toad editor and then execute.

```
Example

explain plan for select field1, field2 from TABLE_NAME;
SELECT * FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check that all queries end with a semicolon, put the cursor on the query you want to analyze and hit **CTRL-E**.

The first time you could get a popup that asks for the name of the plan table, it suggests `TOAD_PLAN_TABLE` but it's better to use the standard Oracle table `PLAN_TABLE` that should be already available.  So enter `PLAN_TABLE` in place of `TOAD_PLAN_TABLE` (do not specify a schema) and hit OK.  You should get a message saying that the object already exists: hit OK again to acknowledge it. Now try CTRL-E again and you'll get the explain plan.

To view/change the currently configured plan table name go to menu "View / Toad Options / Oracle General".