# Getting Actual Execution Plan in Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, toad

I have read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9269042/oracle-execution-plan) and [this](http://blog.jooq.org/2012/09/19/how-to-get-oracle-execution-plans-with-starts-e-rows-a-rows-and-a-time-columns/) excellent article

My question is, how to get the **acutual** execution plan in Oracle 11g

**without** sys privilege and DBA privilege.    (You can treat my case as a READ-ONLY user)

I'm able to get the explain plan using `SYS.PLAN_TABLE$` or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> in `TOAD`

But my understanding is that explain plan = estimated execution plan only?

Found on Oracle's Document

> Execution plans can differ due to the following:

- > Different Schemas
- > Different Costs

Please give me any help you can offer to clear my concepts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use `dbms_xplan.display_cursor`, you'll need [at least these grants](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/appdev.112/e10577/d_xplan.htm#i999214):

```
grant select on sys.v_$sql_plan to larry;
grant select on sys.v_$session to larry;
grant select on sys.v_$sql_plan_statistics_all to larry;
```

And you'll probably also need `V$SQL` to find the `SQL_ID`:

```
grant select on sys.v_$sql to larry;
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips, so I must get these permission on SYS table from DBA?

Comment: one more question. `dbms_xplan.display_cursor` 's result is the actual execution plan used in query?

Comment: Yes.  It can display several "actual" columns, allowing you to compare the estimates with the actual values.

Comment: I'll accept this answer if there's no other workaround in 2 days.

Comment: I'll go with this answer as seemingly there's no other workaround, and I'll like to be granted the minimum set of privilege.

Answer (score 2):

If you're developer, maybe I can request SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE to be granted you. In 11g it is harmless to grant it. This will allow read-only access to most of the information DBAs have.

This will give you an access to v$sql_plan*, v$session_longops, V$lock, V$SQL_BIND_CAPTURE
and other performance related data.

Comment: That would be more convenient than granting individual tables.  But I don't think you can always call it harmless; it depends on the organization.  For example, a lot of organizations would not want developers running `select password from dba_users;`, even if the password is encrypted.  And even `V$SQL` may be problematic, if users are including sensitive information in their queries.

Comment: Yep, you're right. By the "harmless" I meant that on 9i users who had this role could see plaintext password for DBLINKs. This is no more true.