# Oracle SQL cannot explain plan for granted view

Tags: sql, oracle, view, explain

I got the below error message once I want to make explain plan based on select query from view.

```
explain plan 
for 
select id 
from my_view 
where id is not null;
```

> ```
> SQL Error: ORA-01039: insufficient privileges on underlying objects of the view
> 01039. 00000 -  "insufficient privileges on underlying objects of the view"
> *Cause:    Attempting to explain plan on other people's view without
>            the necessary privileges on the underlying objects of the view.
> ```

I have also checked all tables based on view and all these ones were granted for my scheme (select) so it should work. Not sure where is the root problem.

Comment: Are you sure the view isn't built on top of other views, and you don't have privileged on the tables *those* are based on?

Comment: You are right. The view is built on the top of not only tables but there is also one view with non-granted table. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue with a view that I created with my own user.
The view is a join view on tables a and b.
Table a is in a different schema and I have been granted the SELECT privilege.
Table b is in my own schema.
My query does an update on this view (all columns are updatable). It copies data from some columns from table a to table b. So no update on table a.
The query itself works fine because I do no update on table a.
However, explain plan does not work for this query.
The issue was fixed for me by also granting the UPDATE privilege on table a  even though the query does not update tables on that underlying table.