# Oracle Performance with 'NOT EXISTS'

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, not-exists

I am porting some SQL server procedures to Oracle and find an interesting situation where the Oracle SQL statements are dramatically slower than the identical logic using cursors.

On investigation, I think there may be a particualr problem with 'NOT EXISTS' (maybe?).

Here I put 100k leads into TMP_TXN and then use these as a filter to extract records from Payments for which there is no transaction (see the SQL construct below).

```
  INSERT INTO tmp_txn ....
  SELECT ....
  FROM   txn, 
         customers
  WHERE  txn.customer_id = customers.customer_id
         AND customers.customer_status LIKE 'A%'
         AND txn.txn_date BETWEEN start_date AND end_date;
```

then insert into tmp_leads where they are in payments but not in TMP_TXN.

```
   INSERT INTO tmp_leads ....
    SELECT ....
    FROM  payments eap, customers
    WHERE eap.customer_id = customers.customer_id
           AND customers.customer_status LIKE 'A%'
           AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT TMP_TXN.CUSTOMER_ID
                           FROM   TMP_TXN
                           WHERE  tmp_txn.customer_id = eap.customer_id
                                  AND  ....;
```

The explain plan is:

```
Plan hash value: 67643415

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                        | Name                   | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | INSERT STATEMENT                 |                        |   665 |   138K| 15450   (1)| 00:03:06 |
|   1 |  LOAD TABLE CONVENTIONAL         | TMP_LEADS              |       |       |            |          |
|*  2 |   FILTER                         |                        |       |       |            |          |
|*  3 |    HASH JOIN                     |                        |   665 |   138K| 14785   (1)| 00:02:58 |
|*  4 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL            | CUSTOMER_TYPES         |     6 |    36 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  5 |     HASH JOIN                    |                        |   726 |   146K| 14781   (1)| 00:02:58 |
|*  6 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL           | EDM_SEGMENTS_EVENTS    |    23 |   414 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   7 |      NESTED LOOPS                |                        |       |       |            |          |
|   8 |       NESTED LOOPS               |                        |  1297 |   239K| 14776   (1)| 00:02:58 |
|*  9 |        TABLE ACCESS FULL         | EDM_AGREEMENT_PAYMENTS |  1297 |   158K| 12180   (1)| 00:02:27 |
|* 10 |        INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | PK_CUSTOMERS           |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 11 |       TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| CUSTOMERS              |     1 |    64 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 12 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID   | TMP_TXN                |     1 |    81 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 13 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN             | IX_TMP_TXN_TXN_CODE    |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - filter( NOT EXISTS (SELECT 0 FROM "TMP_TXN" "TMP_TXN" WHERE "TMP_TXN"."TXN_CODE"=:B1 AND 
              "TMP_TXN"."CUSTOMER_ID"=:B2 AND "TMP_TXN"."AGREEMENT_ID"=:B3 AND ("TMP_TXN"."AMOUNT"<0 AND 
              "TMP_TXN"."AMOUNT">=:B4*1.1 AND "TMP_TXN"."AMOUNT"<=:B5*.9 OR "TMP_TXN"."AMOUNT">0 AND 
              "TMP_TXN"."AMOUNT">=:B6*0.9 AND "TMP_TXN"."AMOUNT"<=:B7*1.1)))
   3 - access("CUSTOMERS"."CUSTOMER_TYPE"="CUSTOMER_TYPES"."CUSTOMER_TYPE")
   4 - filter("CUSTOMER_TYPES"."ACTIVE"=U'1')
   5 - access("CUSTOMERS"."CUSTOMER_SEGMENT"="EDM_SEGMENTS_EVENTS"."SEGMENT")
   6 - filter("EDM_SEGMENTS_EVENTS"."EVENT_ID"=607 AND "EDM_SEGMENTS_EVENTS"."ACTIVE"=U'1')
   9 - filter(ROUND("EAP"."PMNT_DAY",0)>=19 AND ROUND("EAP"."PMNT_DAY",0)<=31 AND 
              "EAP"."PERIODICITY"=U'M' AND "EAP"."EVENT_ID"=607)
  10 - access("EAP"."CUSTOMER_ID"="CUSTOMERS"."CUSTOMER_ID")
  11 - filter("CUSTOMERS"."CUSTOMER_STATUS" LIKE U'A%')
  12 - filter("TMP_TXN"."CUSTOMER_ID"=:B1 AND "TMP_TXN"."AGREEMENT_ID"=:B2 AND 
              ("TMP_TXN"."AMOUNT"<0 AND "TMP_TXN"."AMOUNT">=:B3*1.1 AND "TMP_TXN"."AMOUNT"<=:B4*.9 OR 
              "TMP_TXN"."AMOUNT">0 AND "TMP_TXN"."AMOUNT">=:B5*0.9 AND "TMP_TXN"."AMOUNT"<=:B6*1.1))
  13 - access("TMP_TXN"."TXN_CODE"=:B1)
```

There is an index on tmp_txn (customer_id), and there are about 100k records in the table. Oracle has 20gb SGA and 20gb PGA, so this should be cached easily.

[Resource plan screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXFiv.jpg)
Here you can see the script running but not using any resources (data reads <100k/sec!).

The (possible) problem seems to be in the NOT EXISTS in that this selection takes >1000 seconds with almost no access of the data tables (resource monitor).
[Stats view in OM showing 898 seconds and 100% cpu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMIkP.jpg)

Am I doing something stupid in Oracle? This works well (and quickly) in SQL Server.

Comment: Why would you be using a temporary table for this logic -- in either database?

Comment: Could you provide query plan?

Comment: Originally the stored procedure used cursors to loop through both large tables (TXN 160m) and payments (20m) and it was easier/faster to extract the actual data (100k-300k)  into a subset for manipulation. There is a lot mor manipulation that is not shown.

Comment: Sorry. I don't know how to extract a query plan. Neither the Explain in SQL developer nor the Plan in enterprise manager seem to be exportable in any readable form (my lack of Oracle knowledge).

Comment: I agree with @VladimirAleshin. It's very hard to tell what's happening without having a look at the plan.

Comment: @Kingbeard, you can read [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30070910/how-do-i-view-the-explain-plan-in-oracle-sql-developer) for more info about extracting query plans

Answer (score 0):

NOT EXISTS should be used if the inner query result set is huge.Please try the below

```
INSERT INTO tmp_leads ....
SELECT ....
FROM  payments eap, customers
WHERE eap.customer_id = customers.customer_id
       AND customers.customer_status LIKE 'A%'
       AND customers.customer_id NOT IN (SELECT TMP_TXN.CUSTOMER_ID
                       FROM   TMP_TXN
                       WHERE  
                       --tmp_txn.customer_id = eap.customer_id
                              --AND  
                          ....;
```

Comment: Thanks @PSARAJ12. I will try this. Hopefully this will help.
Cheers.

Comment: Sadly this didn't make any real difference.

Comment: commented a condition try now

Answer (score 0):

Try using left join instead of creating and loading temptxn then joining

```
Insert into tmpleads
Select ...
From payments eap 
Inner join customers cust
    On cust.customerid = eap.customerid   
LEFT JOIN temptxn txn
    On txn.customerid = eap.customerid
Where txn.customerid IS NULL
```