# Improve SQl query by indexing or aggregated index

Tags: sql, oracle

Assume this general SQL query takes too long to execute. Which of the 4 options below can be done to improve its performance? Why? This is just for the understanding of SQL, not a dbms specific.

1. CREATE INDEX IDX ON Vaccinations (COUNT(*), Site)
2. Wrap the query in a view and ask users to query from the view.
3. CREATE AGGREGATE INDEX ON Vaccinations(COUNT(*))
4. CREATE INDEX IDX ON Vaccinations (Site)

```
SELECT Site, COUNT(*) AS Number of Vaccinations
FROM Vaccinations
GROUP BY Site;
```

A few rows from the `Vaccinations` table is shown here:

[image: Table sample]

Personally, I'm leaning towards 1. Since the `count(*)` is the only thing being used in the `SELECT...FROM` as a condition. However, I'm not entirely sure what the "aggregate index" option entails. Can someone explain when it's preferred over normal index? Thanks!

Comment: Indexing is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: you can look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50863962/speeding-up-queries-that-use-aggregate-functions-by-using-indexes

Comment: How about say, in oracle SQL?

Comment: Run your horses. Get the execution plan with each options and compare. Having said that #4 looks like a decent candidate to read the entire table.